# Unable to boot after accidentally unmounting all disks

Tags: mount, 18.04, fstab

I was having issues with an external hard drive automounting properly, so I stupidly ran the command `umount -a -l` which unmounted all drives including my main drive and swap drive and bootloader.

Now, even after hard rebooting, it just stays stuck at black screen and not booting at all.

How can I fix this without reinstalling the OS?

Comment: You may boot from LiveUSB and run  fsck against your hard drive(s)...

Comment: After mounting it in the live USB it seems that /etc/fstab was modified and doesn't contain the partitions anymore. What should I edit it to to make it work. Or can I just delete it and have it fix itself?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk with the OS on it was listed in fstab, when you reboot it should automatically re-mount it for you. If it wasn't listed there for some reason, perhaps because it was manually edited or something... or if this just isn't working you can use any number of Live boot images on a CD/DVD or on a USB drive. Once you've Live booted you can try manually mounting the drives or fixing your fstab file.

Comment: It seems to have gotten removed as mentioned in the comment above. Thebdisks are no longer listed in my fstab.

Comment: You will need to add the entries back into fstab.

See the following link for more information on fstab. Some people list the disk UUID, but if you give the volume a label you can also tell it to mount using the LABEL name. 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Hope that helps.